# <p:dialog> is not opening on setting ajax=false for <p:upload>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I a new to stackoverflow and primefaces. My application deals with the upload and download functions. In my application there is a  and a button.On clicking the button, actionListener is triggered and  is opened. I am setting ajax=false for getting the file on this button but the dialog is not open. Here is my code

```
<p:fileUpload mode="simple" value="#{UploadFile.uploadedFile}"/>

<p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{UploadFile.submitFile}" ajax="false" />

<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="proceedDialog" >
    <p:commandButton value="Proceed"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" />
</p:confirmDialog>

<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="cancelDialog" >
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel"/>           
</p:confirmDialog>

private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
        return uploadedFile;
    }
public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
}

public void submitFile(ActionEvent event) {
    if(uploadedFile.getSize > 0){
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("proceedDialog.show()");
    } else {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("cancelDialog.show()");
    }
}
```

I am getting the file size but the proceedDialog is not opening.Any suggestions would be very much helpful.I am using primefaces 4.0.jar

Comment: A full-page submit is generally not dialog-friendly. What's `executejavaScript`?

Comment: I have edited the code. Thanks.